# ERROR Failed to perform transaction: Transaction failed with vm status: Validation(UnknownScript)

Tags: facebook, blockchain, rust-cargo, diem

I am following Diem (libra) documentation on [My First Transaction](https://developers.libra.org/docs/my-first-transaction), everything worked fine until Submit a Transaction. As mentioned in the following document, I tried to submit a transaction. https://developers.libra.org/docs/my-first-transaction#submit-a-transaction

But it fails with below error, tried going thru troubleshooting articles, but not much helpful.

```
libra% transfer 0 1 10
>> Transferring
[ERROR] Failed to perform transaction: Transaction failed with vm status: Validation(UnknownScript)
libra%
```

Wondering if anyone able to successfully submit the transaction.

OS: macos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are building the client cli off `master` branch, you may need to build using `testnet` instead. I faced the same issue, it worked after switching to testnet branch.

```
$ git checkout testnet

$./scripts/cli/start_cli_testnet.sh 
.
.
.
libra% transfer 0 1 10
>> Transferring
Transaction submitted to validator
To query for transaction status, run: query txn_acc_seq 0 0 <fetch_events=true|false
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Interestingly it didn't save my previous account details, i got to recreate all again.